# Remove a specific string from the beginning of a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace, match

My code:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
//output of pathname is "/removethis/page/removethis/color.html"


var string = "/removethis/";

if (pathname.match("^"+string)) {
   pathname = preg_replace(string, '', pathname);
}

alert(pathname);
```

The output is:

I try to find out if the beginning of the string is a match to `/something/` and if yes, then remove this string from the beginning of `"pathname";`

What I expect is:

```
page/removethis/color.html
```

But I get the error

```
preg_replace is not defined
```

Comment: `preg_replace` is a PHP function. In JavaScript, you need `string.replace(regex, replacement);`

Comment: `preg_replace()` is a PHP function, not JS. To make this work in JS use [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Comment: I did this now `pathname = pathname.replace(string, pathname);` but now the output is `/removethis/page/removethis/color.html`

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `.replace()` in JavaScript, `preg_replace()` is for `PHP`.

Try this :

```
pathname = pathname.replace(string, '')
```

Comment: yes, this works!

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to do this in one go

```js
var pathname = "/removethis/page/removethis/color.html";

var string = "/removethis/";
var regex = new RegExp("^" + string);
console.log(pathname.replace(regex,""));
```

Comment: This works, but why is RegExp better the replace`

Comment: @fala well, you need regex anyway, because you're checking the beginning of the string with `^` - so may as well do it in one go using regex.replace, rather than do a regex.match and then a string replace.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the quotes from around your regex.

```js
var pathname = "/removethis/page/removethis/color.html";
//output of pathname is "/removethis/page/removethis/color.html"


var regex = /^\/removethis/;

if (pathname.match(regex)) {
   pathname = pathname.replace(regex, '');
}

alert(pathname);
```